# MongoDB - can't insert Mongo object to db

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have a script like this:

```
use first_db;

advertisers = db.agencies.find( 'my query which returns things correctly );

close first_db;
use second_db;

db.advertisers.insert(advertisers);
```

and I get this exception:

```
Tue Jun  5 14:15:07 TypeError: advertisers.toJSON is not a function (shell):1
```

What am I supposed to do? Change the original result to json and then insert it? or is there some function i need to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Your missing a `'` in the above code `db.agencies.find( 'my query which returns things correctly );` should be `db.agencies.find( 'my query which returns things correctly' );` I don't know if thats the problem or if that just krept in when you transfered the code over to stackoverflow...

Comment: @lenny ... :) .... that is a dummy text instead of the actual query that is there :) The problem is in the last line of the code I pasted. The above query works. Also I am not sure if I am closing the first and second dbs correctly.

Comment: hmm okay, that's as far as I can help unfortunately as i have never used MongoDB... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that find() returns a cursor, not the actual data. You need to iterate over the results in the cursor and store them in a variable.

Try taking a look at the these places in the manual: [find()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/javascript/#query-and-update-methods) and [cursors](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/javascript/#cursor-methods).